# Difference in instantiating new Webpack() vs Webpack(config)?

Tags: webpack

I'v seen both versions for creating a new compiler instance.

```
let config = {target: 'web', /* more config */ };

// Version A

let compiler = new Webpack();
compiler.options = config;

// Version B

let compiler = Webpack(config);
```

Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed there is a difference!!!

If you take a look at [this code here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4428efe48e1c5ff4cadb79e13f0fa48c12bdac35/lib/webpack.js#L18) you will notice that the webpack function has 2 arguments!

One is `options` and the second is `callback`[image]

Jumping to halfway down in the image I have attached showing the linked source above, you will notice that there is an `if` statement that looks to see if the callback was provided. If it is a function, then webpack will automatically run the `Compiler.run()` method, and then callback function will be provided the run results.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference.